# Overriding Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product

Tags: magento2.4

Magento 2.4

I have a need to display a custom product attribute called 'promotion_on' in [Backend > Catalog > Categories > {Category from tree } -> Products in Category ] Products grid as an additional column.

I tried doing it with a module with following files. However expected overriding does not happen as it seems. Templatehints are also showing original paths, not the custom module. Can someone please guide me how to resolve this.

Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"/>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
    /**
     * Set collection object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('promotion_on');
        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->addColumnAfter('promotion_on', array(
            'header' => __('Promotion on'),
            'index' => 'promotion_on',
        ), 'sku');

        $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected. You should remove generated directory and re-compile code to see the changes:

```
rm -rf generated
bin/magento:setup:di:compile
```